# How to traverse two same size matrices and compare them

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have two matrices filled with 0s and 1s

```
e.g.
A = [ 0 0 1 0,
      1 0 1 0 ]

B = [ 1 1 1 1
      0 0 0 0 ]
```

and I'd like to compared the values form the same position against each other and return a 2x2 matrice

```
R = [ TP(1) FN(3)
      FP(2) TN(2) ]

TP = returns the amount of times A has the value 1, and B has the value 1
FN = returns the amount of times A has the value 0, and B has the value 1
FP = returns the amount of times A has the value 1, and B has the value 0
TN = returns the amount of times A has the value 0, and B has the value 0
```

How do i get each individual number in A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1:** Comparison based using **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** -

```
pA = [1 0 1 0] %// pattern for A
pB = [1 1 0 0] %// pattern for B

%// Find matches for A against pattern-A and pattern-B for B using bsxfun(@eq.
%// Then, perform AND for detecting combined matches
matches = bsxfun(@eq,A(:),pA) & bsxfun(@eq,B(:),pB)

%// Sum up the matches to give us the desired counts
R = reshape(sum(matches),2,[]).'
```

Output -

```
R =
     1     3
     2     2
```

---

**Approach #2:** Finding decimal numbers -

Step-1: Find decimal numbers corresponding to the combined `A`'s and `B`'s

```
>> dec_nums = histc(bin2dec(num2str([B(:) A(:)],'%1d')),0:3)
dec_nums =
     2
     2
     3
     1
```

Step-2: Re-order the decimal numbers such that they line up as needed in the problem

```
>> R = reshape(flipud(dec_nums),2,[])'
R =
     1     3
     2     2
```

Comment: Second approach -- very original!

Comment: This worked very well, thank you! I just now realised that what i meant was I was working with a binary image (that is filled with 0s and 1s)..which is a little different... do you know how to compare two binary images?

Comment: @GwenWong Compare two binary images and find the similar patterns for A and B and get a `2x2` output?

Comment: @GwenWong If you are looking to get such a `2 x 2` output after comparing those two binary images, then the codes posted here should work right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Use [logical operators](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html) `&` and `~` applied on the [linearized](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) versions of `A` and `B`, and then [`nnz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) (or [`sum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)) to count the `true` values:

```
R = [nnz(A(:)&B(:)) nnz(~A(:)&B(:)); nnz(A(:)&~B(:)) nnz(~A(:)&~B(:))];
```